# npm list does not show installed package

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble understanding `npm`. I have a `node.js` project with `react`, but I am not able to find the latter with `npm list`.

I certainly have it installed, because my project using `react` works.

I also have it in my `package.json` file under "dependencies":

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1"
}
```

Also, if I search for `react` on my drive, I find the module for it in my project folder:

```
user/Dev/project/node_modules/react
```

However, if I do `npm list react`, I get nothing:

```
me ~/D/project> npm list react
project@0.1.0 /Users/me/Dev/project
└── (empty)
```

Even if I do `npm install` or even specifically `npm install react --save`, no change.

Nor is the package listed with `npm list` or `npm list -g` (with or without `--depth=0`), except I get further indications that `npm` does not 'see' the `react` module:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.4.1
```

I'm using `npm v5.6.0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this same issue with react as well.  If I do npm install react@latest it says it has been installed but immediately afterwards if I do npm list react it says it's not there.

Comment: I am also having this problem with react. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I'm having this problem but not with react, but with react-redux library

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by running `npm update` command. (If that doesn't work try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` prior to running `npm_update`)

Comment: Thanks. I have since reinstalled my machine, cloned the project and done a clean `npm install`, which fixed the problem. I tried your suggestion before, which didn't help, although I haven't tried removing `package-lock.json`...

Comment: For me `npm config set link true` was causing the issue. If `link` is `true` then `npm list -g` or `npm ls -g` will return --(empty). Once I set it to false, I was able to view the installed packages.